# material-ui overwrite theme with useStyles / jss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

How can you override the Material-UI theme using styles without using !important?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
     MuiInputBase: {
      input: {
        background: '#dd7711',
        padding: 10,
      },
     },
    },
  },
})

export default makeStyles(theme => ({
  hutber: {
    background: '#000',
    color: '#fff',
  },
}))


function SpacingGrid() {
   const classes = useStyles()
   return <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}><Input label="Outlined" variant="outlined" className={classes.hutber} /></MuiThemeProvider>
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the only way to override the styles are be creating another theme :O I would like to know if `styles`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the override was not working was because specifying the `className` prop is equivalent to specifying the `root` [CSS class for Input](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#css), but your theme overrides are on the `input` CSS class which is applied to a different element (the root element is a div, the input element is an `<input>` element within that div).

In my example below, you can see two different approaches for targeting the `<input>` element. The first approach uses a [nested selector](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule) to target `.MuiInputBase-input`. The second approach uses the `classes` prop (instead of `className`) and provides the overrides as the `input` CSS class.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      input: {
        background: "#dd7711",
        padding: 10
      }
    }
  }
});

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  hutber: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
      background: "#000",
      color: "#fff"
    }
  },
  alternateApproach: {
    background: "#000",
    color: "#fff"
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Input defaultValue="Without overrides" variant="outlined" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Input
        defaultValue="With overrides"
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.hutber}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Input
        defaultValue="Alternate approach"
        variant="outlined"
        classes={{ input: classes.alternateApproach }}
      />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit override input styling from theme]

Comment: I left a question here, trying something for parent base https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72947368/material-form-field-and-textfieldroot-overwrite-theme-with-usestyles-jss