# Material Form Field and TextFieldRoot overwrite theme with useStyles / jss

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I override Material themes for FormControl? It is usually html parent above a Textfield. I want the margin bottom to be 8px, instead of 4px. Below is not working. Currently using MUI version 4

[image]
export const useProcedureTableStyles = makeStyles({

```
  overrides: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      marginBottom: '8px',
    },
  },
  textField: {
    height: '31px',
  },


<TextField
  {...params}
  margin="dense"
  value={listItem}
  error={listItem.duplicateFlag}
  InputProps={{
    ...params.InputProps,
    style: { padding: 0 },
    className: procedureStyles.overrides,
    classes: {
      input: procedureStyles.textField,
    },
  }}
/>
```

Researching this resource: [material-ui overwrite theme with useStyles / jss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454378/material-ui-overwrite-theme-with-usestyles-jss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simplified version of the html structure shown in your screenshot:

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root">
   <div class="MuiOutlinedInput-root">
      <input type="text" class="MuiOutlinedInput-input"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

You are passing `procedureStyles.textField` via the `input` key of the `classes` prop in `InputProps`. That targets the innermost `input` element (and I assume that is working as intended). That `input` element can also be targeted using the `className` property of `inputProps` (lowercase `i`).

You are passing `procedureStyles.overrides` via the `className` property of `InputProps`. `InputProps` targets the second `div` in the structure above (the one with `class="MuiOutlinedInput-root"`), and then your margin bottom styles are being applied to any descendants of the `div` that have a class of `MuiTextField-root`. Since the `div` you want to target is an ancestor of that second `div` and not a descendant, your styles have no effect.

To target the first `div` in that structure, you can use the `className` prop directly on `TextField`. It would also be equivalent to use the `root` key of the `classes` prop directly on `TextField`.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  overrides: {
    marginBottom: "8px"
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div>Something before to demonstrate top margin</div>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        margin="dense"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.overrides}
      />
      <div>Something after to demonstrate bottom margin</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit override FormControl styles of TextField]

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your Material-UI theme:

```
overrides: {
  MuiFormControl:{
    marginDense:{
      marginBottom:'8px'
     }
   }
 }
```